# Processing output from HTTP call made in node.js

Tags: javascript, http, callback, node.js

I'm playing around with node.js and want to process some text that comes back from Twitter's API. I installed [node-get](https://github.com/tmcw/node-get) to help.

The following sample code works:

```
var dl = new node_get('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json');
dl.asString(console.log);
```

and I get the raw output printed to the console. What I'd really love to do is get that output back as a string directly, but asString takes a callback as a parameter. What I want to do is block the code execution until the string is returned. Is there a way to do that?

The code is being used in a dispatcher, and I can't continue the dispatch until the response from the call comes back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't any (native) way to block the process while waiting for `asString`

If you absolutely must have blocking, you could take a look at [node-fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers). Keep in mind, though, that fibers (and blocking) go against the core design of the language. Non-blocking is your friend!